# How can I calculate some location Open and Close Time with Current Time

Tags: swift, if-statement, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I want have an restaurant application and i want to improve my functionality. I have the restaurants **Open and Close time** with `NSDate` Format. I want to simple **check which restaurants is open currently**. My app should ask the `NSDate()` for current time and it should be check the Open and Close time. `If current Time <= Close Time & current Time >= Open Time` restaurant should be **open**. `If current Time >= Close Time and & currentTime <= Open Time` restaurant should be **close**.

What is the best approach for this situation ? 
Should I go for If else statements as I told ?

Comment: An NSDate is an absolute point in time. How can it describe an opening time (which is a recurrent event, e.g. 8am every morning) ?

Comment: Yes. I am using NSDateComponents() and NSCalendarUnit().hour and .minute to get openingTime hour and minute and I have to get current time hour and minute with NSDateComponents as well. After that I have to check the hour and minutes with if else statement. I mean I don't know what is the best approach which is the main question for me.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using an if-else statement (conditional) is a good approach. This is how I would go about this (`openTime` is opening time and `closedTime` is closing time):

```
// Set up calendar and unit flags

let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

let timeUnitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.CalendarUnitHour, .CalendarUnitMinute]

// Retrieve components

let openComponents = calendar.components(timeUnitFlags, fromDate: openTime)
let closedComponents = calendar.components(timeUnitFlags, fromDate: closedTime)
let currentComponents = calendar.components(timeUnitFlags, fromDate: NSDate())

// Convert components into minutes into the day

let openMinutes = (openComponents.hour * 60) + openComponents.minute
let closedMinutes = (closedComponents.hour * 60) + closedComponents.minute
let currentMinutes = (currentComponents.hour * 60) + currentComponents.minute

// Check if open or closed

if currentMinutes >= openMinutes || currentMinutes <= closedMinutes {
    // Open
} else {
    // Closed
}
```

However, the code above does not address closing times after midnight or other calendars.

Comment: Why || operator is being used, instead of && operator to find out whether some location is open.